# SSIS - Column names as Variable/Changed Programmatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me out with this one - I have 24 files in CSV format, they all have the same layout and need to be joined onto some pre-existing data. Each file has a single column that needs to be joined onto the rest of the data, but those columns all have the same names in the original files. I need the columns automatically renamed to the filename as part of the join.

The final name of the column needs to be: Filename - data from another column.

My current approach is to use a foreach container and use the variable generated by the container to name the column, but there's nowhere I can input that value in the join, and even if I did, it'd mess up the output mappings, because the column names would be different.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how to get around these issues? Whoever has an idea will be saving my neck!

**EDIT** In case some more detail helps with this... SSIS version is 2008 and there are only a few hundred rows per file. It's basically a one time task to collect a full billing history from several bills which are issued monthly.

The source data has three columns, the product number, the product type and the cost.

The destination needs to have 24*3 columns, each of which has a monthly cost for a given product category. There are three product categories, and 24 bills (in seperate files) hence 24*3.

**So hopefully I'm being a bit clearer - all I really need to know how to do, is to change the name of a column using a variable passed in from the foreach file container.**

Comment: Do you want the names of the column changed after you perform a join ?

Comment: If I were to restate your problem. In each source file, you need to acquire the data in one column and append it to an existing output (file?). This process needs to be repeated for all the source files. Further complicating matters is the appended output columns need to be named, partially, after the source file.

Comment: If all of that is accurate, my further questions would be-are these 24 files static or do they vary (in count and names). When you say you need to join this data, are we talking about a lookup/merge join transformation or more generally, you need to tie or link this data together? What version of SSIS will you be using (2005 or 2008+) What sort of data volume are we talking about 100 rows, 10k, 10M?  Is this a one-time task or an ongoing process?

Comment: billinkc - Yes, your first comment is 100% correct. 

The 24 files will vary in names, as each name is bill data for one month in CSV format.

Using SSIS 2008, and with approximately 500 rows, so not a lot of data. It's a one time task also.

Comment: Sorry Praveen, just re-read your comment. Yes, the final name of the column in the database must be the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to create a tmp database (aka staging db)
to load data from xls file to it and to define **stored procedures** where you can pass paramas (ex file names etc) and to build your won logic ...
Cheers Mario